Ginkgo tree with yellowing leaves
I bought a two foot tall ginkgo tree.  I dug a hole that was deep and wide.  I refilled hole with some potting soil so I didn’t plant the tree too deep.  Some of the leaves have turned yellow.  I have been watering the tree every other day unless it rains. Any ideas why the leaves are yellowish. The tree is in full sun.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Pictures please
